# How To Resolve a Car Accident Using Bayesian Theorem?

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian

The probability that a one-car accident is due to
faulty brakes is $0.04$, the probability that a one-car accident
is correctly attributed to faulty brakes is $0.82$, and the probability that a one-car accident is incorrectly
attributed to faulty brakes is $0.03$. What is the probability
that

$(a)$ a one-car accident will be attributed to faulty brakes;

$(b)$ a one-car accident attributed to faulty brakes was
actually due to faulty brakes?

Is my interpretation of this problem correct? If so can I continue and use the Rule of total probability and conditional probability?

$B_{1} = \{ \text{Car accident due to faulty brakes \}}$

$B_{2} = \{ \text{Car accident NOT due to faulty brakes \}}$ (refers to elements not in $B_{1}$)

$P = \{ \text{attributed to brakes}\}$

$N = \{ \text{NOT attributed to brakes}\}$

$P(B_{1}) = .04 \; \; \;P( B_{2})= .96$

$P(P|B_{1}) = .82$

$P(P|B_{2}) = .03 $

$P(N|B_{1}) = 1-.82 =.18$

$P(N|B_{2}) = 1-.03 = .97 $

Comment: Your interpretation is my interpretation, although your choice of event names is a bit odd.  Why $B_1, B_2$, but $P, N$? ¶ At any rate, you are then looking for (a) $P(P)$ (see why this is a bit awkward?); and (b) $P(B_1 \mid P)$.

Comment: I think  $P$ as in positive and $N$ as in negative it is easier to remember what one is doing.

Comment: Do imprecise language and notation lead to confusion among $P(P|B_1),$ $P(B_1|P)$ and $P(P \cap B_1)?$ There is certainly confusion between 'brake' and 'break'.

Comment: @BruceET I guess I might have had other things in mind lol. I will fix this.